# Equivalent method of ".getComputedTextLength()" in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

What is the equivalent of `.getComputedTextLength()` method in `d3`. `.getComputedTextLength()` works on `Dom` element not `d3` element's object.
**Edit (Image added)**
[image]

Answer (score 14):

D3 selections are, in fact, objects (since D3 v4.0). However, there is no method for computing the length of the text in an object because the object itself has no presence in the DOM and, therefore, has no length. You can only compute the length (in pixels) of a DOM element.

That being said, you can use `getComputedTextLength()` with a D3 selection, if you use that selection to point to the SVG element. For instance, using `node()`:

```
d3.select("foo");//this is a D3 selection
d3.select("foo").node();//this is the DOM element
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var text = svg.append("text")
 .attr("x", 10)
 .attr("y", 30)
 .text("Hello world!");
 
console.log("the text has " + d3.select("text").node().getComputedTextLength() + " px")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: `d3.select("foo").node();` is still returning `d3` object (not DOM element). I am working in salesforce

Comment: There is not need to to do a `.select()` since you already have the d3 object in `text`, so `text.node().getComputedTextLength()` is all you need.

Answer (score 4):

Simply access the DOM elements inside selection operations with `this` to benefit from bulk node processing customary with `D3`, e.g.

```
d3.selectAll('tspan.myClass')
  .each(function(d) {
    console.log(this.getComputedTextLength());
  });
```

or

```
d3.selectAll('tspan.myClass')
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    var width = this.getComputedTextLength() + 2 * padding;
    return 'translate(' + width / 2 + ' 0)');
  });
```

`this` is [bound to the current DOM node](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_selectAll).

`selection.node()` [only returns](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_node) the first element in the selection.

As of `D3` 4.* there's also `selection.nodes()` which recovers [all DOM nodes](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_nodes) in a selection, so you can do

```
d3.selectAll('tspan.myClass').nodes().forEach(function(el) {
  console.log(el.getComputedTextLength());
});
```

though its use is less idiomatic than grabbing the element via `this` inside `selection.attr`, `selection.style`, `selection.filter`, `selection.each` etc. as in the snippets above it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, OP wants to have a function similar to `getComputedTextLength` in D3.js, without using D3.js.

There's not such method in plain Javascript. However, if the element is an SVG element, you can use `getBBox()` to retrieve the coordinates and dimension of the *smallest rectangle* that the element fits.

If the element doesn't belong to an SVG, use `getClientRect()` or `getBoundingClientRect()`.

Answer (score 0):

Its `node.getBoundingClientRect().width`.

In my case, `this` is a d3 object. So you can use `getComputedTextLength()` to get the width of the object.

If you are using plain javascript, you can use `node.getBoundingClientRect().width`.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Please post code examples as text. So prefer **code blocks or snippets.** Screenshots should only be used as additional info.

Comment: @herrstrietzel So you mean `node.getBoundingClientRect().width` is not code? 
I think the answer here is just this one line of code. Any suggest for this case?

Comment: Take inspiration from @Gerardo Furtado's answer:
Explain the problem (D3 objects need a context (each/this) or D3 methods like `node()` to be selected as regular DOM elements). Include a code snippet. 
In fact, your example screenshots also proves, `getComputedTextLength()` works perfectly fine as long as you're getting the native node from the D3 object.  
In fact the OP's description should include a **proper code example** as well.
Since my comment might have provoked other SO users to downvote your answer – I've upvoted to give yo a chance to revise your answer.