# WebStorm TypeScript debugging: error already happened way before debugger was attached

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm, jsdom, javascript-debugger

I followed this [blog](https://medium.com/@kandros/getting-started-with-typescript-debugging-with-webstorm-breakpoints-f88aab1ffe5d) on how to set up debugging TypeScript for WebStorm, and I think I pretty much got it, debugger looks like working correctly. But when I set breakpoints in my TypeScript code it doesn't get hit and when I look into my console, it looks like the error already happened way before WebStorm is able to attach the debugger.

[image]

I looked into other articles on how to setup the debugger and they're all pretty much the same, so wondering how come this is happening.

Here are some the configs in my WebStorm project:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "include": [
        "src/scripts/*.ts",
        "src/scripts/*.js"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules", "typings"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015.promise",
            "es6"
        ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "./typings", "./node_modules/@types"
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

FWIW, I'm particularly debugging a set of code which tries to wrap texts in d3.js. I'm following this [snippet](https://blocks.org/mbostock/7555321), especially the `wrap` function, but in my case I have to convert it to TypeScript which then results into this:

```
function wrap (text: d3.Selection<d3.BaseType, {}, d3.BaseType, any>, width: number) {
    text.each(function () {
        let text = d3.select(this);
        let words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse();
        let word;
        let line: string[] = [];
        let lineNumber = 0;
        let lineHeight = 1.1; // ems
        let y = text.attr('y');
        let dy = parseFloat(text.attr('dy'));
        let tspan = text.text(null).append('tspan').attr('x', 0).attr('y', y).attr('dy', dy + 'em');
        while (words.length > 0) {
            word = words.pop();
            line.push(word);
            tspan.text(line.join(' '));
            let node: SVGTextContentElement = tspan.node() as SVGTextContentElement;
            if (node.getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                line.pop();
                tspan.text(line.join(' '));
                line = [word];
                tspan = text.append('tspan').attr('x', 0).attr('y', y).attr('dy', `${++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy}em`).text(word);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I'm particularly having problem with the `getComputedTextLength`, in my TypeScript definitions. The function is there, but somehow JavaScript can't find it. I already tried what was answered in this previous [StackOveflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42718947/2475170), didn't worked for me, so I tried searching the `node_modules` which type defines the `.getComputedTextLength`, thus explains the `SVGTextContentElement`, but still the error.

[image]

BTW, I'm using **node version v7.10.0** and **[jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom)** to emulate the browser

Comment: Not sure how you pass the parameter to node in webstorm but you have to use the `--inspect-brk` to stop execution on entry so no code executes before the debugger attches  https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Comment: hello @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, thank for the immediate response, but i've added those node parameters and still the same thing happens. I've updated the screenshots with the recent debug configurations

Comment: your are using d3 for DOM manipulations... such code is normally run in browser. What steps do you normally perform to run your code (not in debugger/WebStorm, forget about IDE)? Is it a server-side app run with Node.js, or client-side code loaded in browser?

Comment: your application crahes before the first breakpoint is hit - likely because you are trying to run your code in a wrong environment (Node.js) instead of running it in browser.

Comment: hello @lena, yes it's a server-side script run with NodeJS, basically a script which creates an html with svg's inside. So does that mean that the debugger only works if it's run with the browser? because i dont use the browser for this particular project.

Comment: btw @lena, I'm using [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) to emulate the browser, it's kind of a lightweight headless browser

Comment: i see. Debugger does definitely work for Node.js apps. But your application crashes with TypeError, and this problem is hardly related to debugger.

Comment: hmm.. that's interesting @lena , I tried removing the above function and place a breakpoint somewhere else, I'm not getting a TypeError anymore but the debugger is still failing to stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: most probably, smth is wrong with sourcemaps. does debugging work if the breakpoints are created in the generated .js files?

Comment: alright you may be correct, debugger did indeed worked on the generated JS script, i'm gonna go check the sourcemaps, thanks @lena